# Json partison jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm new to jQuery and I found one example and by using that example I parsed my json string as below, but I found all outputs as undefined instead of value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
    var jsonp = '{"members":[{"User_name":"Vrushank","Email":"eqr@ewr.in"},{"User_name":"dfdaf","Email":"afafi@df.in"},{"User_name":"vimlesh","Email":"vimlesh@lidsfdthe.in"},{"User_name":"nirav","Email":"havsr@lifgffe.in"},{"User_name":"parth","Email":"vasavada@zfs.in"},{"User_name":"fsd","Email":"test.test@gmail.com"}]}';
    var lang = '';
    var user = '';
    var email = '';
    alert(jsonp);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    //alert(obj);
    $.each(obj, function() {
        lang += this['members'];
        alert(lang);
        $.each(lang, function() {
            user = this['User_name'];
            email = this['Email'];
            $('span').append(user +":"+email+"<br/>");
            user="";email="";
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have two `$.each` calls. Just do:

```
$.each(obj.members, function(i, member) {
       $('span').append([member['User_name'], ':', member['Email'], '<br/>'].join(''));
});​
```

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frederikring/4Embv/)**

The **[jQuery docs on $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)** do have a pretty good example of how to loop through JSON-data with the use of **[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**